# Tab control not selecting first item in observable collection WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I notice that the `TabControl` that has its `ItemsSource` property bound to an `ObservableCollection` does not select the first item in the collection if you do the following:

1. Load `TabControl` when the `ObservableCollection` has a count of 0 (tab items are not showing)
2. Add an item to the `ObservableCollection`, observe that one `TabItem` is now present but not selected

If you add an item to the `ObservableCollection` **before** the `TabControl` comes into focus for the first time, the one item in the `TabControl` has its `TabItem` selected. It only seems that when the tab count hits 0 then increases again does it seem to lose its ability to select the first item.

It seems this is by design. Is there any way to get around this issue?

I have the following tabcontrol definition in XAML as follows:

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sels}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the name `tabControl` to your `TabControl`, then you could subscribe to the changes in its items collection in code-behind:

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sels}" x:Name="tabControl" />
```

```cs
tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
```

and then you can force it to select the first tab if none are selected:

```cs
private async void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs e) {
    await Task.Yield();
    if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == -1) {
        if (tabControl.Items.Count > 0) {
            tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The call to `await Task.Yield()` is needed to let WPF finish handling internal `TabControl` updates before changing its `SelectedIndex` property.

---

**To be extra fancy**,

you could put this in an [attached `DependencyProperty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview) and *in fine* have a cleaner XAML and no extra code-behind:

```xml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Sels}" local:AutoSelect.AutoSelectFirstTab="true"/>
```

Here is the same behaviour but wrapped using WPF attached `DependencyProperty`:

```cs
public static class AutoSelect {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoSelectFirstTabProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "AutoSelectFirstTab",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(AutoSelect),
        new PropertyMetadata(false, AutoSelectFirstTabChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoSelectFirstTab(TabControl obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoSelectFirstTabProperty);
    public static void SetAutoSelectFirstTab(TabControl obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(AutoSelectFirstTabProperty, value);

    private static void AutoSelectFirstTabChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        var tabControl = (TabControl)d;
        tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemsChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged;
        async void ItemContainerGenerator_ItemsChanged(object _1, ItemsChangedEventArgs _2) {
            await Task.Yield();
            if (GetAutoSelectFirstTab(tabControl)) {
                if (tabControl.SelectedIndex == -1) {
                    if (tabControl.Items.Count > 0) {
                        tabControl.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Omg Corentin if I wasn't married I'd say something other than thank you!!!! You're a life saver :)! I was trying all sorts.. I got so depressed... I tried binding SelectedIndex to my VM (using MVVM and Caliburn Micro), and it didn't work... when I set it to 0 it would then automatically trigger and set it to 1 (there was no index 1 :( ). If I didn't touch it and it was at -1, then it wouldn't automatically update itself to go to 0. Was driving me mad... I even tried SelectedItem instead.. no luck.. Why it doesn't work with binding and works with a behaviour I won't know...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Corentin's answer I just want to add that, depending on the way you fill that `ObservableCollection`, you might also just assign the first item to a designated property in the viewmodel.

In my case which is pretty similar to yours I process exported plugins collected from a MEF container in code. When that is finished I just update a property `SelectedPlugin` in the viewmodel and in XAML I then do a *TwoWay*-binding on `SelectedItem` of the `TabControl` to this property.

This works perfectly and serves exactly your use-case.